# Verified Email Addresses check in AWS Simple Email Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have encountered a weird issue using the AWS Simple Email Service.

There is a verified email address in the service configuration written like this: `Foo.BAR@mail.com`, and when an email is sent programmatically to the address `foo.bar@mail.com` an exception is thrown complaining that `foo.bar@mail.com` is not verified.

Is this a known issue? It seems rather strange that addresses are checked this way by SES. Are we expected to verify all combinations with capital letters in SES?

Comment: Is the email address setup for receiving emails ?. If yes, how? Also, SES is popularly used for `sending` emails rather than receiving.

Comment: I don't understand your comment @kintuparantu. If you send an email on one hand, that usually means you're sending it to another email address receiving it on the other hand, right? So what's the point of your question?

Comment: Recipient address verification is only used in testing.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Comment: I'm aware of the verification in sandbox mode @Michael-sqlbot, but that is not the question. The question is rather about how that verification is performed.

Comment: There's a concept of POP/IMAP for receiving emails and SMTP for sending emails. SES provides SMTP out of the box for sending emails but for receiving, you have to configure a mailbox with proper MX records and other stuff. So my question is, how are you handling the emails for receiving. Where is the mailbox located and are the MX records properly set ?

Comment: @kintuparantu, we are indeed sending emails to a bunch of verified public email addresses of various providers addresses, no 'mailbox configuration' involved. The question here is how SES checks the destination email to see if it's verified or not, that's it.